# Manually installing an ISO onto a USB?

Tags: iso, dd

I'm trying to install TAILS. I've downloaded and verified it and everything and I'm on to installing it. I want to install it manually onto a USB stick. The TAILS website doesn't have any instructions for doing this on Ubuntu, only on Linux: https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/installation/manual/linux/index.en.html

I've followed the steps for Linux, but when I get to doing the actually copy, this is what my terminal shows:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ dd '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/tails-i386-1.5.iso' of=/dev/sdc bs=16M && sync
dd: unrecognized operand ‘/home/ubuntu/Desktop/tails-i386-1.5.iso’
Try 'dd --help' for more information.
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

So how do I manually install the TAILS ISO onto a USB? I'm a beginner and I've just been following step-by-step guides to get this far. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As you're a reputation 6 user: If the answer below helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 4):

You forgot the `if=` so using the correct syntax and `sudo` **;-)** you get:

```
sudo dd if=/home/ubuntu/Desktop/tails-i386-1.5.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=16M && sync
```

---

From `man dd`:

```
if=FILE
      read from FILE instead of stdin
```

Comment: Thank you! I now get a "permission denied" error though.

Comment: Sorry, forgot the `sudo` in front

Comment: @Aja As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of the answer, which means "yes, this answer is valid"! ;-)

Comment: You should also provide instructions as to how to 'undo' dd as `dd` alone can prevent USB reusability.